# "Сопротивление стало поддержкой" Можно ли так говорить?

Tags: фразеология, лексика

Контекст: Определенный уровень был сопротивлением цене, потом его пробили и этот же уровень стал поддержкой цене. (Форекс)
Можно ли сказать в данном контексте что "Сопротивление стало поддержкой"?

Answer (score 1):

"Становление" допускает смену свойств их носителя ("он" был белым, стал чёрным; аналогично, "уровень" был сопротивлением, стал поддержкой), но не означает взаимопревращения *самих свойств* - для этого нужен другой глагол. Не говорят "белизна стала чернотой", "мир стал войной" и т. п. Поэтому высказывание "сопротивление стало поддержкой" внутренне противоречиво: нечто стало собственной противоположностью, оставаясь самим собой. В отрыве от носителя свойств (здесь "уровень") правильнее сказать: сопротивление *сменилось (обернулось)* поддержкой.

Comment: "сопротивление сменилось (обернулось) поддержкой." - это из какой-то другой сферы. На бирже эти понятия не так устроены, чтобы меняться или оборачиваться.

Answer (score 0):

Это профессиональный язык брокеров и игроков на бирже. Людям со стороны не всегда понятен. А не понимая до конца смысла, невозможно сказать, что тут правильно, что нет.

На мой дилетантский взгляд, стопроцентно правильно было бы говорить не об уровне, который был сопротивлением, а стал поддержкой, но об уровне поддержки и уровне сопротивления и т. д. Т. е. уровень по смыслу не есть поддержка или там сопротивление, но может *соответствовать* тут *быть равным* уровню, *при котором происходит эта поддержка*.

А вот насколько справедливо перенесение одного понятия на другое - это только профессионал скажет. В принципе нет ничего запретного, таки вещи в языке встречаются, это своего рода метонимия.

И еще не могу не заметить, если вы принимаете за норму "уровень был сопротивлением", то и "стал поддержкой" надо признать нормальным. Это явления совершенно одного порядка. Ну на мой взгляд, конечно.

Comment: *А вот насколько справедливо перенесение одного понятия на другое - это только профессионал скажет*  - не профессионал, но скажу. Совершенно несправедливо, даже невозможно по смыслу.

Answer (score 0):

Нет. ***"Уровень сопротивления стал уровнем поддержки"*** - только так и не иначе, если только вы не хотите внести сумятицу в головы читающих.

Попробую пояснить. Это ключевые понятия рынка акций. На торгах всегда есть некие ценовые "уровень сопротивления" и "уровень поддержки" (кроме периода сверхажиотажного спроса и панического сброса, когда подобные понятия просто не применимы, но обычно торги в таких случаях просто приостанавливают). Эти два уровня образуют коридор, в котором и торгуются акции. Со временем границы коридора дрейфуют в ту или иную сторону. Быстрое превышение курса над уровнем сопротивления называется "пробоем снизу", понижение ниже уровня поддержки - "пробоем сверху". Вот примерно смысл всех этих терминов.

Таким образом, ни "поддержка" никогда не станет "сопротивлением", ни наоборот, это принципиально разные вещи, они по смыслу не могут превратиться друг в друга. И даже если (в динамике) один уровень станет соответсвовать другому, то это чисто условное состояния равенства, а не перехода или "превращения" одного в другое.